# CSS selector checkbox and label

Tags: css, sass

can someone help me out, I have searched alot, but without luck, maybe I am searching the wrong way. Because, I thinks is pretty simple

How can I with CSS / SCSS change the background color of a label when a checkbox inside is checked?

HTML

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{tag.key}}" />
    {{tag.name}}
</label>
```

SCSS

```
label {
  background: $balanced;
  color: #fff;
}
/* - my bad try - */
label + input[type='checkbox']:checked  {
  background: $positive;
}
```

Comment: You can't with CSS only ... move it outside, before and you can .. or add a span inside/after and color it

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048368/change-checkbox-label-css-property-with-checkbox-checked)

Comment: thanks for you help!